# Unable to requests FastAPI running in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, fastapi

I have a Dockerfile which exposes an API on port 8000:

```dockerfile
# ..

EXPOSE 8000
ENV PYTHONPATH="src/."
CMD ["gunicorn", "-b :8000", "-k", "uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker", "fingerprinter.api.server:app"]
```

It's just a simple FastAPI server with a simple endpoint:

```py
@app.get("/health")
def health():
    return "OK"
```

This is the relevant part of the `docker-compose.yaml`:

```dockerfile
version: "3.7"

services:

  fprint-api:
    container_name: fprint-api-v2
    image: "fprint-api:v0.0.1"
    depends_on:
      - fprint-db
      - fprint-svc

    network_mode: "host"
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    expose:
      - "8000"

    build:
      context: ../.
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile.fprint-api
```

However, I am not able to reach the endpoints.

Comment: Since you disable Docker networking with `network_mode: host`, normal connections between containers won't work.  Does deleting this line make a difference?  (You also don't need `expose:`, `container_name:`, or `image:`, and you probably don't need the `extra_hosts:` either.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expose in Dockerfile does not really publish the port [Dockerfile - EXPOSE](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose). It is more like a
'documentation' for a reader of Dockerfile, it shows that the port is intended to be published.

In `docker-compose.yml` you map port from docker container to host system by using `port`, [Docker compose - ports](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports). In `docker-compose.yml` keyword `expose` exposes port only for the linked services, it does not publish the port to the host machine [Docker compose - expose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#expose)

So your `docker-compose.yml` file should look like this:

```yaml
version: "3.7"

services:

  fprint-api:
    container_name: fprint-api-v2
    image: "fprint-api:v0.0.1"
    depends_on:
      - fprint-db
      - fprint-svc

    # network_mode: "host"
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"

    build:
      context: ../.
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile.fprint-api
```

Comment: Note: `network_mode` does not work in combination with `ports`. Fun fact: Changing `"8000"` to `"8000:8000"` did the trick..

Comment: Yes, when using only "8000" syntax the port on the host machine is chosen randomly.